# Dispatch KeyHandler event to new DOM target with Google Closure (or plain Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, clojurescript, keyboard-events, google-closure-library

I have a web-application that needs to capture any keyboard event on the page, and target them to the appropriate `editable-div`.

- If the `editable-div` has focus, then the event flows to my event handler and to the DOM to push the character corresponding to the key into the `DIV`.
- However, if the `editable-div` is not the current focus target, I am able to capture the event with my event handler, but the character corresponding to the key pressed is not pushed into the `DIV`.

My previous implementation had a dependency on jQuery, and `$.trigger()` was doing the right thing: moving the keyboard event from a non-matching target to the default `editable-div` I choose.

I am trying to achieve the same without jQuery, and with Google Closure. I tried various incantations of [dispatchEvent](http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/interface_goog_events_Listenable.html) without success in triggering the new virtual keypress.

In ClojureScript, trying to do something naive such as

```
(.dispatchEvent new-target (.getBrowserEvent event))
```

will cause the browser to complain that `The event is already being dispatched.`

Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Comment: `goog.events.fireListeners(someInputText, 'change', false,{ type:'change', target:someInputText});`? Otherwise `goog.testing.events` should do this.

Comment: `fireListeners` didn't work. I didn't know `goog.testing.events`, but it did not work either: `(goog.testing.events/fireKeySequence new-target (.-keyCode event))` is almost good as it will trigger my `on-key-event` function with an event that looks correct, but it still does not push the key in the `editable-div`.

Comment: ah `fireKeySequence` from `good.testing.events` works. I just had to make sure to `(.focus new-target)` focus the target before simulating the event. @Andre Could you add your reply as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `goog.testing.events/fireKeySequence` to create events similar like jQuery's `trigger`.

[More](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/closure-library-discuss/dispatchEvent/closure-library-discuss/6q6xPNriZt4/z47UEB_nFK0J) [discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/cEtEsx_M42o).